binarySearch() misidentifying index value
Hopefully a short question, troubleshooting a demo a beginner student brought to my attention.
        int[] nums = {2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 0, 9, 6};
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));  //prints sorted array
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(nums, 6));

//sorted array is:  [0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]
Code is in a generic main method.  It's returning 11 instead of 10, the first instance of the value 6. if I take one of the 6s away it identifies properly as 10.  Why?
Thank you.
Short aside, the textbook states that it will return -1 if it doesn't find the value. Instead it returns (-(insertion point) - 1) A little confusing, but the negative tells the important part (not found).

"the textbook states that it will return -1 if it doesn't find the value" the textbook is wrong.

Have you consulted the method's Javadoc to find out why it would return 11 instead of 10?

No reason the code should return the first entry with the value, returning the index of the second entry is just as valid.  learn how the  search works and it will make sense.

instead the textbook, I would thrust the javadoc - it clearly states "If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found." and "Returns:
index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)" (original emphasis)

From the Javadoc:

If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found.

That is, depending on the implementation you are using, you might have got 11, you might have got 10.
If you need to find the first, search backwards from the found element.

I thought the whole point of binSearch was it started at index-0 and went until 1) found or 2) anything higher was found and it stops??

No, that would be linear search.

@Skelefish - You need to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm.  Binary search doesn't work the way that you think.
